# Implementing a select element in my form, but unsure how to grab user selection for a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have implemented this select list, provided by Volker Otto on Codepen here:
http://codepen.io/l4ci/pen/gPjYma/

I find it works perfect for me, however I dont know how to process the user selection for this select list because its not an option list.

any ideas?

Find below markup, css and js:

```
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 325px;
  color: #cccccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.select .placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #393d41;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select .placeholder:hover {
  background: #34383c;
}
.select .placeholder:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f078';
  z-index: 10;
}
.select.is-open .placeholder:after {
  content: '\f077';
}
.select.is-open ul {
  display: block;
}
.select ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
.select ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.8em 1em 0.8em 1em;
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li:hover {
  background: #4ebbf0;
  color: #fff;
}

$('.select').on('click','.placeholder',function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  if ( ! parent.hasClass('is-open')){
    parent.addClass('is-open');
    $('.select.is-open').not(parent).removeClass('is-open');
  }else{
    parent.removeClass('is-open');
  }
}).on('click','ul>li',function(){
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  parent.removeClass('is-open').find('.placeholder').text( $(this).text() );
});
```

```js
$('.select').on('click', '.placeholder', function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  if (!parent.hasClass('is-open')) {
    parent.addClass('is-open');
    $('.select.is-open').not(parent).removeClass('is-open');
  } else {
    parent.removeClass('is-open');
  }
}).on('click', 'ul>li', function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  parent.removeClass('is-open').find('.placeholder').text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
 *,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8e9eab, #eef2f3);
}
body {
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 325px;
  color: #cccccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.select .placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #393d41;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select .placeholder:hover {
  background: #34383c;
}
.select .placeholder:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f078';
  z-index: 10;
}
.select.is-open .placeholder:after {
  content: '\f077';
}
.select.is-open ul {
  display: block;
}
.select.select--white .placeholder {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
}
.select.select--white .placeholder:hover {
  background: #fafafa;
}
.select ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
.select ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.8em 1em 0.8em 1em;
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li:hover {
  background: #4ebbf0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <span class="placeholder">Select your language</span>
  <ul>
    <li>España- Español</li>
    <li>United States - English</li>
    <li>France - Français</li>
    <li>Deutschland - Deutsch</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>

<div class="select select--white">
  <span class="placeholder">Select your language</span>
  <ul>
    <li>España- Español</li>
    <li>United States - English</li>
    <li>France - Français</li>
    <li>Deutschland - Deutsch</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i assume that the selected value will be stored in the span.. get the value of that span to get the selected value. `span with the class placeholder`. One more thing if you have a demo you can create a snippet for it SO have that functionality to make the *OP not lose the demo when LINK rots*

Comment: @guradio good advice, thanks

Comment: did it work? glad to help happy coding :)

Comment: @guradio I meant about adding the snippet..I haven't tried it yet...some code would be helpful, im still learning...the snippet doesnt seem to be doing the js, not sure why but thats all the code there..

Comment: you were not able to include the jquery script that is why it is not working check the answer i provided you can see a comment and alert in the code there you are setting the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.select').on('click', '.placeholder', function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  if (!parent.hasClass('is-open')) {
    parent.addClass('is-open');
    $('.select.is-open').not(parent).removeClass('is-open');
  } else {
    parent.removeClass('is-open');
  }
}).on('click', 'ul>li', function() {
  
  alert($(this).text())//this is the value of the text you selected
  var parent = $(this).closest('.select');
  parent.removeClass('is-open').find('.placeholder').text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
 *,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8e9eab, #eef2f3);
}
body {
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 325px;
  color: #cccccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.select .placeholder {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #393d41;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select .placeholder:hover {
  background: #34383c;
}
.select .placeholder:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f078';
  z-index: 10;
}
.select.is-open .placeholder:after {
  content: '\f077';
}
.select.is-open ul {
  display: block;
}
.select.select--white .placeholder {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
}
.select.select--white .placeholder:hover {
  background: #fafafa;
}
.select ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
.select ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.8em 1em 0.8em 1em;
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li:hover {
  background: #4ebbf0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- You did not include this on your OP -->
<div class="select">
  <span class="placeholder">Select your language</span>
  <ul>
    <li>España- Español</li>
    <li>United States - English</li>
    <li>France - Français</li>
    <li>Deutschland - Deutsch</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>

<div class="select select--white">
  <span class="placeholder">Select your language</span>
  <ul>
    <li>España- Español</li>
    <li>United States - English</li>
    <li>France - Français</li>
    <li>Deutschland - Deutsch</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I added the alert where you are setting the value check the comment in code

Comment: @Krystyna have check the demo is that what you expect?

Comment: okay, so that .alert in the js you added, do I use that to grab user selection and if so how do I validate that a list item has been selected also?

Comment: the value of `$(this).text()` is the selected value. you can validate on click of the list because after clicking the list you have selected a value and that value is `$(this).text()`. unlike directly getting the value from span (which by the way has a value on load)

Answer (score 0):

You might use this to get the value in jquery :

```
jQuery('div.select .placeholder').html();
```

Comment: interesting. So where abouts in the js do I put this, and do I modify the html code at all as well?